# Couchdb query view limit

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

When querying documents in a view, is there a limit to the number of documents that is shown if `limit` parameter is not mentioned?

This [link](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) does say that `Columns can be a list of values, there is no set limit to the number of values or amount of data that columns can hold.`

But not sure if it means we can put any number as limit or by default it has no limits. I just want to know if by default when the limit parameter is not mentioned, is there any limit to the number of outputted docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CouchDB, [the default behavior for a view is to return all results](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/views.html#using-limits-and-skipping-rows), so you must specify a `limit` parameter if you want to do some sort of pagination or return a subset of the data.

Comment: It's not the case with mango queries where the default limits to 25 results. Do you know if there is a way to make a mango query return all the results or if I should just specify an arbitrary high limit ?

Comment: @zlr For `MangoQuery`'s you *have* to set a limit. If you'd like to query all documents through a mango query you should set an arbitrary high limit or use `total_rows` of the /{db}/_all_docs view and use it as a limit. The latter solution requires an additional http request, but is possibly more future proof.

Comment: As [noted in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73613494/260675), this is now (as of 2022) incorrect. The default limit for CouchDB is now 25.

Answer (score 2):

As an update to others landing here in 2022: Default limit is 25 for find.

see: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/api/database/find.html

> limit (number) – Maximum number of results returned. Default is 25. Optional

Note: any old API not providing a limit like js:`Number.MAX_VALUE` will cap at 25 - sorting and limiting afterwards will give strange results.